# asynchronous triggers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gridview and detailsview controls. The detailsview will be displayed only for the edits of the gridview. My detailsview is in an update panel and it will be displayed on the same page.

I have a button inside the detailsview. When the button is clicked the itemcommand doesn't trigger and moreover, it causes a full post back. My page gets refreshed and I lose the data from the detailsview and only gridview is displayed.
Any ideas for overcoming it?

Thanks

Comment: can, you provide the coding which you have used in the button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the full-postback problem, have you tried to use `ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Control control)` passing the button as "control"?

Comment: no but where should i register that ., I display and bind my gridview in the rowcommand of the gridview., in the pageload I cant bind it because it is not find the control .

Comment: Yes, you should use the events of the grid to access your button.